# How do I count rows according to criteria and save it as vector?

Tags: r, count, criteria

I would like to count the rows of a dataframe according to the value of a vector and save the result as  a new vector. So, for example I have

```
c1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1)
```

Now I want to know how many times c1 ==1, c1==2 and so on.
So my result for the new vector should be

```
c2 = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3)
```

Can anybody help? :D And please explain as simple as possible, I'm rather new to this :D

Thaaanks

Comment: Where is your dataframe?

Comment: For your example this would work: `table(c1)[c1]`

Answer (score 3):

Try `ave`

```
> ave(c1,c1,FUN = length)
[1] 3 1 2 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```r
as.numeric(table(c1)[match(c1, names(table(c1)))])
#> [1] 3 1 2 3 2 3
```

---

To explain this a bit (and make gratuitous use of SO's new table feature) if we start with `table(c1)` we get:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

Which tells us how many of each number appear in the vector.

If we do `names(table)`, we just get the 1, 2, 3 from the header of the table as a vector. That means we can match each member of our original vector to one of the columns of this table by doing `match(c1, names(table(c1)))`. This will give us, for each member in `c1`, the column of the table we want to use as the counts for our new vector. To get the counts from the column numbers, we just subset the table with the column numbers, so `table(c1)[match(c1, names(table(c1)))]`. This gives us our answer, but just to keep the whole thing clean, we remove the distracting column names from our result with `as.numeric`

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
with(rle(sort(c1)), lengths[match(c1, values)])

[1] 3 1 2 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also an option:

```
as.numeric(table(c1)[as.character(c1)])

[1] 3 1 2 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table`

```
table(c1)[c1]
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(c1)[, c2 := .N, c1]$c2
#[1] 3 1 2 3 2 3
```